# Can not retrieve data from Django Rest Framework response, when use ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, python-3.x, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm tring to consume my Django Rest API with jquery ajax. I write a simple view:

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
def hello_world(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return Response({"message": "Got some data!", "data": request.data})
    return Response({"message": "Hello, world!"})
```

And sumple consuming frontend code:

```
            $('#redirect').click(function(){
                var data = {key1: "value1"};
                console.log('redirect button clicked');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/",
                    "data": data,
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log('success');
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        },
                    failure: function(errMsg) {
                        console.log('failure');
                        console.log(errMsg);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

I receive success code in backend:

```
[24/Oct/2017 08:44:05] "GET /test/?callback=jQuery21100695833324387296_1508823842460&key1=value1&_=1508823842461 HTTP/1.1" 200 27
[24/Oct/2017 08:44:06] "GET /test/?callback=jQuery21100695833324387296_1508823842460&key1=value1&_=1508823842462 HTTP/1.1" 200 27
```

And receive nothing in frontend:

```
redirect button clicked (08:44:06:227 | null)
  at public_html/index.html:112
redirect button clicked (08:44:06:885 | null)
  at public_html/index.html:112
```

I know I loose something simple but cannot find out. Please advise me what's wrong in my code.

UPD. Change frontend code:

```
            $('#redirect').click(function(){
                var data = {key1: "value1"};
                console.log('redirect button clicked');
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/",
                    "data": data,
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log('success');
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        },
                    failure: function(errMsg) {
                        console.log('failure');
                        console.log(errMsg);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Still have same problems.

UPD2. Add output for request.data:

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
def hello_world(request):
    print(request.data)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return Response({"message": "Got some data!", "data": request.data})
```

Receive:

```
<QueryDict: {}>
[24/Oct/2017 13:57:19] "GET /test/?callback=jQuery21109646247308520148_1508842562290&key1=value1&_=1508842562293 HTTP/1.1" 200 27
<QueryDict: {}>
[24/Oct/2017 13:57:20] "GET /test/?callback=jQuery21109646247308520148_1508842562290&key1=value1&_=1508842562294 HTTP/1.1" 200 27
```

UPD3. Change ajax requesting part of frontend:

```
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/",
                    "data": data,
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function(inp_data){
                        console.log('success');
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(inp_data));
                        alert(JSON.stringify(inp_data));
                        },
                    error: function(arg1, errMsg) {
                        console.log('failure');
                        console.log(errMsg);
                        }
                    });
```

Got in frontend output:

```
failure (15:23:58:959 | null)
  at public_html/index.html:124
parsererror (15:23:58:961 | null)
  at public_html/index.html:125
```

UPD4: Change my frontend code again:

```
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/",
                    "data": data,
                    success: function(inp_data){
                        console.log('success');
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(inp_data));
                        alert(JSON.stringify(inp_data));
                        },
                    error: function(xhr, errMsg) {
                        console.log('failure');
                        console.log(errMsg);
                         console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });
```

Now I have right request in backend:

```
 <QueryDict: {'key1': ['value1']}>
[24/Oct/2017 15:52:12] "POST /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 53
```

But still have a trouble in frontend:

```
failure (16:00:25:706 | null)
  at public_html/index.html:123
error (16:00:25:708 | null)
  at public_html/index.html:124
0: undefined (16:00:25:710 | null)
  at public_html/index.html:125
```

Comment: As in your logs, your ajax code somehow sent a get request to your server so you must have gotten the response accordingly i.e. missing data. Instead of type POST I think you should use method: POST

Answer (score 0):

You should use `method: "POST"` in your front end ajax code. By default it is sending *GET* request so you are not getting expected results. Refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have just changed my frontend code, but nothing change nor in frontend output, nor in backend.

Comment: Can you print request.data in your views and show it?

Comment: Also I did not find any `failure` callback option in jquery ajax api docs. Although there is availability of `error` callback function.

Comment: I have just added my request data in upd of first post. I also change "failure" with "error"- it return obj.

Comment: What is _obj_? Also I have doubt in request method as according to your logs your server is receiving a _GET_ request. Can you confirm it? Also what is the output of the latest update on front end?

Comment: Yeah, my server receive get request, and my frontend log parseerror(see UPD3)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157374/discussion-between-a-bykov-and-aquaman).